# Ability to select start and end point on audio player

Tags: javascript, audio, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to have a audio player with waveform on front end and ability to select start point and end point on the audio player and send these point to back end to trim the audio. Also if I can drag these points on the audio player to select the specific part, that would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: HTML5 Video API

Comment: Where is the code you tried so far? Please [edit] and create a [mcve]. If in doubt, please read [ask].

Comment: https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js#readme

Comment: @GetSet I'll check the HTML5 Video API. Thanks

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I've used HTML 5 audio player so far and have used it's on seek handler to select start and end time but it's not user interactive. I've checked the wavesurfer.js it has audio player with waveform but could not find any example or event handler to select audio start and end time.

Comment: Have you tried with https://wavesurfer-js.org/example/regions/index.html ? (https://wavesurfer-js.org/) I'm not exactly sure how to do it with Wavesurfer - or if it's an out-of-the-box feature, but, once you have the waveform drawn, should not be that hard to overimpose a DIV element with two draggable bars. Than calculate the transformation from PX to MS. But in that case I'm not sure how to (on play) play that region only... perhaps like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60503478/how-do-i-play-a-region-and-only-the-region-on-wavesurfer-js

Comment: Thanks @RokoC.Buljan The example you shared was really helpful and I googled a bit on how to get the updated region, this is what I got ***wavesurfer.on('region-updated', (obj) => console.log(obj.start, obj.end))*** and it worked like I wanted it to. Thanks again. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan if you comment this then I can select it as correct answer.

Comment: @NoManIlyas you're welcome to provide an answer to your own question with the code necessary to help a future visitor with the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## JavaScript trim audio file

Here's how I did it using https://wavesurfer-js.org/

```js
const EL_play = document.querySelector("#play");
const EL_loop = document.querySelector("#loop");

const RegionsPlugin = WaveSurfer.regions;
const wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
  container: "#waveform",
  waveColor: "#999",
  progressColor: "#000",
  mediaControls: true,
  loopSelection: true,
  plugins: [
    RegionsPlugin.create(),
  ],
});

const Trim = {
  loop: EL_loop.checked,
  options: {
    id: "Trim",
    start: 0,
    color: "rgba(0, 100, 255, 0.1)",
  },
  time: 0,
  create(re) {
    this.options.start = 0; // Set Trim start
    this.options.end = wavesurfer.getDuration(); // Set Trim end to match audio duration
    wavesurfer.addRegion(this.options); // Add Trim region to WaveSurfer instance
    this.Region = wavesurfer.regions.list[this.options.id];
  },
  trimTime() {
    const wasPlaying = wavesurfer.isPlaying();
    const re = this.Region;
    const isEnd = this.time >= re.end;
    this.time = Math.min(Math.max(wavesurfer.getCurrentTime(), re.start), re.end);
    if (isEnd) this.time = re.start;
    if (isEnd && !this.loop) wavesurfer.pause();
    wavesurfer.setCurrentTime(Math.max(0, this.time)); // https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/issues/1816
  },
  play() {
    wavesurfer.playPause();
  },
};

const updateUI = () => {
  EL_play.classList.toggle("isPlaying", wavesurfer.isPlaying());
};

EL_loop.addEventListener("change", () => Trim.loop = EL_loop.checked); // play pause events
EL_play.addEventListener("click", () => Trim.play()); // play pause events
wavesurfer.on("region-updated", () => Trim.trimTime());
wavesurfer.on("ready", () => Trim.create());
wavesurfer.on("play", updateUI);
wavesurfer.on("pause", updateUI);
wavesurfer.on("audioprocess", () => Trim.trimTime());
wavesurfer.load("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg"); // Load Sound!
```

```css
.wavesurfer-region {
  z-index: 0 !important; /* Place Trim "background" below the wave */
  pointer-events: none; /* Ignore mouse on trim region */
}

.wavesurfer-handle.wavesurfer-handle-start,
.wavesurfer-handle.wavesurfer-handle-end {
  width: 5px !important; /* Easy way to prevent handlers disappear due to width 1% */
  pointer-events: auto; /* Allow mouse on trim handlers */
}

.wavesurfer-handle.wavesurfer-handle-start {
  background-color: #0bf !important;
}

.wavesurfer-handle.wavesurfer-handle-end {
  background-color: #f0b !important;
}

#play:before { content: "\23F5"; }
#play.isPlaying:before { content: "\23F8"; }
```

```html
<div id="waveform"></div>
<button id="play"></button>
<label><input id="loop" type="checkbox" checked> Loop</label>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js/dist/plugin/wavesurfer.regions.min.js"></script>
```